# FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 when trigger dispose. Why?

Tags: java, rx-java, kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following RxJava 2 code (in Kotlin), which have an Observable that

```
disposable = Observable.create<String>({
    subscriber ->
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000)
                subscriber.onNext("Test")
                subscriber.onComplete()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                subscriber.onError(exception)
            }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe({ result -> Log.d("Test", "Completed $result") },
             { error -> Log.e("Test", "Completed ${error.message}") })
```

While it is still `Thread.sleep(2000)`, I perform `disposable?.dispose()` call, it will error out

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Process: com.elyeproj.rxstate, PID: 10202
java.lang.InterruptedException 
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:371)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:313)
    at presenter.MainPresenter$loadData$1.subscribe(MainPresenter.kt:41)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
```

I expect the `dispose` would help to cancel the operation silently, or at most, have the error catch with with the `Log.e` on the subscribe. However, it just crash as per the error message above.

Why did the Exception escape? Isn't `dispose` suppose to cancel the entire operation silently without crashing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a combination of factors here:

1. `dispose` of a stream that uses `subscribeOn` also disposes of the thread used. This also involves calling `Thread.interrupt()` when using `Schedulers.io()`. This causes the exception in your case.
2. `InterruptedException` is an `Exception` thrown by `Thread.sleep`, so it is caught by your code and passed to `onError` like any other exception.
3. Calling `onError` after `dispose` redirects the error to the global error handler due to RxJava2's policy of NEVER throwing away errors. To work around this check `subscriber.isDisposed()` before calling `onError` or use RxJava 2.1.1's new `subscriber.tryOnError`.

   ```
   if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) {
     subscriber.onError(exception)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Kiskae. that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rxjava2, please add this in your initialisation code

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(t -> {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,null, t);
    });
```

Hope it helps